# Wildcard SSL is installed, but sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't

Tags: ssl, wildcard-subdomain

I have a annoying problem on my website. I've installed a wildcard certificate today, which seems to work fine.

The browser does accept the certificate and my website is safe. But sometimes when I'm using my website, the certificate isn't valid anymore. And then when I refresh it suddenly is.

Does anyone knows where to start searching?

I'm using DirectAdmin. I've used Let's Encrypt and a Wildcard certificate from Sertigo.

Website is kolaber.com, and every subdomain (*.kolaber.com) should be safe.

https://decoder.link/sslchecker/kolaber.com/443

- Tried another certificate authority

Comment: I checked the certificate on kolaber.com it was issued for srv1.beezdesign.nl . Make sure you set a valid certificate on your server or hosting. If you own a VPS and you are personally managing the certificates, You have to make sure that SNI (Server name indication) is checked in ssl configurations.

Comment: Hmm strange, I have enable SNI in DirectAdmin but still have this issue. Why is it still using the srv1. certificate

Comment: I think it works now. Updated DirectAdmin and changed the hostname. Does it work there as well now?

Comment: Hmm didn't work. Still get the same error message. I've checked everything in the directadmin.conf and SSL settings. Very strange and never happened before.

Comment: You need to activate SNI for all hosted websites on a same OS. If you are not the owner of the server there is missconfiguration in server hostings which mixes the domains!